# spring @Autowire with scala 2.8

Tags: spring, scala, autowired

When I do:

```
class XX {
    @Autowired var jdbcTemplate : SimpleJdbcTemplate = null
}
```

The code compiles fine but blows up when I start the webapp. It gives:

```
SEVERE: StandardWrapper.Throwable
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/collection/immutable/List
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2389)
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:1836)
at      org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.determineCandidateConstructors(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:227)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.determineConstructorsFromBeanPostProcessors(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:930)
```

How do I fix this? Btw I get the same error when I try to @Autowire the constructor.

Comment: With 2.7.2 compiler the code works but in that version I have to explicitly provide a setter method.

Comment: But the injection works with the 2.7.7 compiler...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that version of Scala runtime library in your runtime environment matches version of Scala compiler. Currently it looks like your code was compiled against Scala 2.8.x API, but runtime environment uses Scala 2.7.x.

Comment: I'm using maven-scala-plugin with scalaVersion set to 2.8.1. I'm pretty sure maven takes care of that part.

Comment: my bad...I updated the compiler version but no the maven dependency version! Your comment forced me to look....thanks!